# How get string message with exit code from c# file to provide .bat file that runs it

Tags: c#, batch-file, error-handling, exit-code

I'm running a c# .exe file like this:

```
runas /user:company\username "D:\company\Batch\dir\program.bat
```

so that's running

```
start /d "D:\company\Batch\dir" program.exe > program.txt
```

I'm trying to get error info to show up in program.txt.

I've been looking at exit codes for c#, but it doesn't look like I can give it specific error info.  [error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exitcode?view=net-5.0).  Does anyone know how I can give the error code specific error info from the c# program?  Like I could give TimeoutException, Exception, CommunicationException, service response error message/code, db connection failure, etc. I'd hate to provide a generic failure, when I know info on the failure to give.

Comment: In the setup above, it seems like any output from Console.WriteLine() in the C# program ought to end up in program.txt - have you tried that yet?

Comment: Yes, right now I do have some Console>Writelines in the failing area, but the text file is empty. I'm not sure if it's because when we run the program a secondary window pops up and disappears when done running it?

Comment: Just a quick redirection to try - in the batchfile, try adding a redirection as follows:

start /d "D:\company\Batch\dir" program.exe > program.txt 2>&1

Comment: I tried that and the text file is still empty.  We tried opening a command window logged in as username, and we ran the .bat file without runas (and without redirect), and the error messages appear on the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like console.writeline's are showing in command window as follows.

We open a separate windows command window, and run it like this:
(where command window is logged in as other user)

C:\Users\stillShowsOriginalUsernameHere>D:\company\Batch\dir\program.exe

Then it shows error messages in command window.  So when I schedule it with the scheduler, it will capture the output as error info.